# Use Gradle function from other gradle file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, maintainability

I want to split my 300 lines build.gradle logically into multiple build files to make it easier to maintain and extend.

As I've noticed, it is possible to split gradle tasks into multiple files and use them with:

```
apply from: "myGradleFile"
```

With this approach I sadly have no access to **functions**, defined in the **second** build script.

**Is it also possible to split Gradle functions into multiple files?**

Example:

Let's say I have my **default build.gradle** with a Task which uses a function

```
task doSomethingWithMyFunction {
    myFunction()
}
```

Now I have **functions.gradle**

```
def myFunction(){
}
```

So I want to access **myFunction** defined in **functions.gradle** from **build.gradle**

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Please provide an example.

Comment: I´ve added a simple example which should make it clearer now.thx

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to be done with functions, but if you turn the functions into closures the following example will work well:

**lol.gradle**

```
project.ext.lolFunction = {
   println it
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'lol.gradle'

ext.lolFunction(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

See 59.4 at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html

You can move your functions to a

```
buildSrc
```

directory.