# How can I call a function from a separate .gradle file from a gradle script using the Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Basically I want to do exactly this:

[Use Gradle function from other gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796146/use-gradle-function-from-other-gradle-file)

which is to say, call one function in one gradle script from another.  The wrinkle is that my build.gradle is in Kotlin (build.gradle.kts) and the script my function is in is still in groovy.

I followed the above link for groovy-to-groovy, but I can't get this to work using the Kotlin DSL.

In my groovy file, functions.gradle, I have:

```
def buildVersionName() {
        //Do some stuff
}
```

And

```
ext {
    buildVersionName = this.&buildVersionName
}
```

Then, in my build.gradle.kts script, I have:

```
apply(from = "functions.gradle")
project.ext.buildVersionName()
```

When I sync, I get the error:

```
Unresolved reference: buildVersionName
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: I wondered how this can be done with Kotlin scripts alone and ended up using `buildSrc` (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html).

Comment: Maybe the following will help you: https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/ (at the bottom there is a chapter about interoperability with Groovy (with a [link to another interoperability chapter speaking about accessing functions on a Groovy object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#the_kotlin_dsl_groovy_builder))).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `build.gradle.kts` do the following:

```
import groovy.lang.Closure
apply(from="functions.gradle")
val buildVersionName: Closure<Any> by ext
buildVersionName()
```

Comment: @elect, `buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    apply(from = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder/master/scripts/SetupBuilderVersion.gradle")
    val setupBuilderVersion = project.extensions.extraProperties["setupBuilderVersion"] as groovy.lang.Closure<*>
    println(setupBuilderVersion())
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092938/calling-a-function-declared-in-a-third-part-gradle-file-from-within-the-buildscr