# Calling a function declared in a third part gradle file from within the buildscript construct

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I;m porting to Grade Kotlin Script the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = URI("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        apply(from = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder/master/scripts/SetupBuilderVersion.gradle")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.de.inetsoftware:SetupBuilder:" + setupBuilderVersion())
        classpath "gradle.plugin.io.sdkman:gradle-sdkvendor-plugin:1.2.1"
    }
}
```

where `setupBuilderVersion()` is a function defined in `SetupBuilderVersion.gradle`

I tried to declare `val buildVersionName: groovy.lang.Closure<Any> by ext` before the `buildscript` and within the `dependencies` but both failed to work (`ext` remains unresolved)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buildscript {     
   repositories { 
        maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") } 
   }
   apply(from = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder/master/scripts/SetupBuilderVersion.gradle") 
   val setupBuilderVersion = project.extensions.extraProperties["setupBuilderVersion"] as groovy.lang.Closure<*> 
   println(setupBuilderVersion()) 
}
```